# Translation from Hebrew to English of Ecclesiasticus 4:20

Tags: versification

I would like to find the Hebrew   translation to Ecclesiasticus 4:20. The source of my query is the clock pictured in this article - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_St._Mary%27s_Cathedral - As one can see, it is attributed  to 4:23. I believe this is a mistake. If someone is able to provide an original translation to 4:20  I would be most appreciative. Thank you. Phil

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  Not all the Hebrew text has been recovered so we rely upon the Greek translation - many exist - you link here quotes the translation of the Latin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [WikiSource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%91%D7%9F_%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%90_%D7%93) Hebrew transcription of David Kahana's edition of Ben Sira (Ecclesiasticus) from the year 1912, verse 20:

> בְּנִי עֵת הָמוֹן שְׁמֹר וּפְחַד מִרָע, וְאֶל נַפְשְׁךָ אַל תֵּבוֹשׁ

The differences in the verses between the Hebrew and English editions is due to differences between the Hebrew manuscripts and the English translations of the Greek translations found in many English Bibles.

The Hebrew MSS for chapter 4 do not have the English verses 4:1 and the Hebrew verses 16-19 are parallel to the English verses 17-22 but differ somewhat in content and order.

The translation of "עת המון" is difficult. This is apparently an idiomatic phrase meaning "when a crowd gathers" or "when everyone says something". My translation of the Hebrew verse 20 is:

> Son, be careful at the time of a crowd for fear of doing wrong, don't be ashamed to follow your own judgement.

The gist of the proverb seems to be, "Beware of following the crowd when it leads to a bad end. Don't be afraid to use your own judgement even if it is unpopular".

Note the divergence between this understanding of the verse and the Greek or Vulgate translations from which we get:

> Son, Observe the Time and Fly from Evil

In the Hebrew, there is no word "fly", just "guard" or "watch out for". The Hebrew version includes the word "המון" ("crowd", "gathering", or the noise of a crowd) which the English version omits.

Comment: Thank you, Abu. Very helpful. The brief quote I referred to in the photo of the clock at Saint Mary's church in San Francisco is an English translation of the Latin vulgate. So two generations removed from the source.    I appreciate taking the time to answer my question. Phil

Comment: @PhilKnight Thanks. I added a little more explanation to my answer regarding the translation. The Ben Sira style is notoriously short and cryptic. Even so, it surprised me to see the divergence in translations for this verse. I don't know the Greek and Vulgate versions, only the Hebrew, so I don't know how to explain the divergence.